# Javascript object to mongodb structure, won't bubble

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, object

So to explain the title further, I am trying to **convert a javascript `Object` into MongoDB structure** for querying.

**As you may know, mongodb has strict matching when it comes to querying the database. In other words, the documents have to match exactly.**

For example, say we have a mongo document with the following layout:

```
{
  location: {
    city: "Some city",
    state: "Some state",
    color: {
      red: "and yellow",
      green: "and gold"
    }
  }
}
```

To query for the city, you would do something like:

```
{
  "location.city": "Some city"
}
```

rather than:

```
{
  "location": {
    "city": "Some city"
  }
}
```

Hence the reason for the birth of this function. The function below does not seem to ?`bubble`? the results up the object. Additionally, the old `object` from the structure is also copied.

**The function:**

```
function query_to_mongo(query, root) {
  var new_query = {};

  for (var property in query) {
    if (!(typeof(query))[property]) {

      if (!root) { // root object.
        root = property;

        // Property value is type of object.
        if (typeof(query[property]) === 'object') {
          new_query = query_to_mongo(query[property], property);
        } else {        
          new_query[property] = query[property];
        }

      } else {

        console.log('Last prop: ' + root + '.' + property);

        // Property value is type of object.
        if (typeof(query[property]) === 'object') {
          new_query[root + '.' + property] = query_to_mongo(query[property], property);
        } else {
          new_query[root + '.' + property] = query[property];

      }

    } 
  }

  return new_query;
}
```

**The code:**

```
var this_query = {
  location: {
    city: "Some city",
    state: "Some state",
    color: {
      red: "and yellow",
      green: "and gold"
    }
  }
};

console.log( query_to_mongo(this_query) );
```

**The Result:**

```
{
  location.city: "Some city",
  location.color: [object Object] {
    color.green: "and gold",
    color.red: "and yellow"
  },
  location.state: "Some state"
}
```

**Expected:**

```
{
  location.city: "Some city",
  location.color.green: "and gold",
  location.color.red: "and yellow",
  location.state: "Some state"
}
```

**So the question is, what is happening? Further, is there a better, more elegant way to accomplish my needs?**

Comment: Are you routinely doing queries like that? This conversion only would work in the most simple of cases. What about all of the operators and such that don't map to your alternative structure?

Comment: Routinely, yes. I understand it would only work only with simple cases. One solution around that would be to build a map that allows only the operators I'd allow. For example `$exists`.

Comment: It should be further explained, that this allows clients to compose a query object from the web. I can't really think of any security problems with this as the `find()` method is called server-side and goes through a type of filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: Although the old answer still works, there is a newer and more elegant solution if you're using nodejs / iojs.**

**The solution:** [flat](https://github.com/hughsk/flat)

**Install:**

```
$ npm install flat
```

**Example:**

```
var flatten = require('flat')

flatten({
    key1: {
        keyA: 'value 1'
    },
    key2: {
        keyB: 'value 2'
    },
    key3: { a: { b: { c: 2 } } }
})
```

**Result:**

```
{
    'key1.keyA': 'value 1',
    'key2.keyB': 'value 2',
    'key3.a.b.c': 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, after a few hours I've finally figured out how to accomplish my task. Additionally, I have also decided to add a map of operators I will allow to be used.

**Code:**

```
function apply_operator(op) {
  switch(op) {
    case "$exists": return true;
    case "$in": return true;
    default: return false;
  }
}

function query_to_mongo(query) {
  var new_query = {};

  (function(obj, val) {
    val = val || '';

    if (typeof(obj) !== 'object')  return true;

    for (var property in obj) {
      if (arguments.callee(obj[property], val + "." + property)) {
        if (apply_operator(property)) {
          new_query[val.substring(1)] = JSON.parse('{"' + property + '": "' + obj[property] + '"}');
        } else {
          if (val.substring(1)) {
            new_query[val.substring(1) + "." + property] = obj[property];
          } else {
            new_query[property] = obj[property];
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return false;
  })(query);

  return new_query;
}

var this_query = {
  location: {
    city: "Some city",
    state: "Some state",
    color: {
      red: "and yellow",
      green: "and gold",
      gold: {
        best: "ever"
      }
    }
  },
  exister: { "$exists": true }
};

console.log( query_to_mongo(this_query) );
```

**Result is:**

```
[object Object] {
  exister: [object Object] {
    $exists: "true"
  },
  location.city: "Some city",
  location.color.gold.best: "ever",
  location.color.green: "and gold",
  location.color.red: "and yellow",
  location.state: "Some state"
}
```